# How to specify git email address on the command line?

Tags: git

I'm working with two different Git repositories (ie github and stash) and for each one I want to use a different email address. I know I can use `git config` but I don't want to have to remember to do this each time I create a new workspace. So, I'd like to create an alias that sets the email address on the command line. Can this be done?

I suppose I could create a script (as opposed to an alias) that'll `git config`, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there IS a simpler way.. why would it be useful to have different email address's, and why is it a requirement that you have so many different email addresses for different repos? - nevertheless - what @Karktik specified, or as you said - a script would be the way to go.

Comment: @sircapsalot, Github is for public projects and Stash is for internal projects. I use my personal email for Github and my company email for Stash. Why is it a requirement that I use only one email address across all repos?

Comment: Will the email address be something different for every repo you create?

Comment: @Code-Guru, the email address will be different depending upon whether I'm using Stash or Github. Actually, there are times I might want to use my company email for some Github projects (ie those my company has open-sourced).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following (bash-style) functions:

```
workgit () {
   GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Work Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="work@work.com" GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Work Name" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="work@work.com" git "$@"
}

homegit () {
   GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Home Name" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="home@home.com" GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="Home Name" GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="home@home.com" git "$@"
}
```

Then you can just call `workgit` or `homegit` in place of `git` to force a given username/e-mail.

This is not an ideal solution (because sometimes you just want to be the committer and not the author, such as when you are rebasing or git am'ing patches) but so long as you are aware of that, you can work around it.

Comment: Awesome approach to this problem. I really like it!

Answer (score 3):

Go to the root of your repo and edit the `.git/config` file

Here you can place this on top

```
[user]
    email                   = you@something.com
    name                    = Full Name
```

Essentially, you are setting these credentials for the repo separately (instead of globally)

Hack

Add this function to your `.bashrc` and run `wgit` on the repo

```
wgit() {
  echo "[user]" >> .git/config
  echo "    email = you@something.com" >> .git/config
  echo "    name  = Full Name" >> .git/config
}
```

Comment: I would have to remember to do that each time I want to override the setting.

Comment: Having this setting in your the repo's git config overrides the global. Just add this to your work repos and the rest will use the global config settings

Comment: I have multiple (on the order of dozens of) workspaces. I create a new one for each task I'm working on.

Comment: Then you need to prioritize what's important and more common. This is a workflow issue. Create a bash alias that adds those 3 lines to the local config so you just run `wrepo` after `git init`

Comment: If you are on github.com, you can authorize your work email addr there as well. So you use your work email to commit to everything

Comment: creating an alias is exactly what I want to do. It's clearly stated in my post. I'm asking if there's a command-line option to help do this.

Comment: Added bash function to the answer

Comment: I would have to remember to run that function. If I have to remember to run the function, I might as well remember to run `git config`.

Comment: typing 4 letters vs lines.. your choice

Comment: It's the remembering that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `git config` with `--global` it saves it for your user across the entire system.  Without that flag it saves the settings only for the current repository.  Repository settings override system settings.

Or, if you want to avoid typing each time you clone, you can simply wrap the clone in a script and call the script.

```
#!/bin/sh

USERNAME="My Name"
EMAIL="myemail@example.com"

git clone $1 $2
cd $2
git config user.email $USERNAME
git config user.name $EMAIL
cd -
```

Set your username and email in the script and run like this, which clones the repository into a folder named `my_folder`.

```
./clone.sh https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2.git my_folder
```

Comment: Yes, I understand I can use `git config`. I said I don't want to have to remember to do that each time I create a workspace. IOW, if I use `git config --global user.email`, I would still have to remember at the time of workspace creation to do `git config user.email` whenever I want to override the setting.

Comment: Try the script I just added.  Really the only way to do this is either script it (and wrap `git clone`) or give yourself a command line alias to run after each time you clone.  You can obviously enhance the script to specify username/email pairs or something more sophisticated depending on exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small shell script to initialize your repository. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
git init
if [ "$1" = 'g' ];
then
  git config user.email <Github email>
fi

if [ "$1" = 's' ];
then
  git config user.email <Stash email>
fi
email=$(git config user.email)
echo "Created repository with $email"
```

I know I'm a bit late, but it took some time to write it...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git config --global user.email='my-personal-email-address'

$ cat stash
#!/bin/bash

git config user.email='my-company-email-address'
git "$@"
```

Emil's solution is the best one for my purposes, but I'll leave this one up in case someone else prefers it.

Comment: The reason some people are asking for it on the command line is because when we checkout from microsoft azure, it changes the email address to be @dev.azure.com and completely and totally ignores what's in the git config.